# How to map domain name to my Java application which runs on Tomcat server

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, proxypass

I have installed both apache2 and tomcat7 on my ubuntu14.04 droplet. Apache is running on default port 80 and tomcat7 on 8080. I have an application deployed on tomcat and to access it, the url looks like:
www.mysite.com:8080/Application_name/

But i want my application to come up when user just enters www.mysite.com

How to configure this?

Comment: are you taking about DNS ?

Comment: yes I am talking about dns

Comment: well what has that got to do with java?  See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_series/an-introduction-to-managing-dns

Comment: java application is web application

Comment: The url didn't helped me

Comment: you are pretty vague aren't you.  Ask a concrete question and you may get some help

Comment: You need to bind hosts name with your application IP in `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: For more detail about modify hosts file: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/modify-manage-hosts-file-linux/

Comment: I have edited the question. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure Apache to be a reverse-proxy from / to /application_name, this will hide the application context for the end-user.

Enable all LoadModule for the proxy, and add

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/application_name/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/application_name/
```

Comment: I did it in **/etc/apache2/sites-available/tomcat.conf**.....and also added a line **ServerName www.mysite.com**  It is worked finally

Comment: I have an another doubt...the above lines works for an application..when I try to publish another application and opening it with URL **www.mysite.com/Application2/** is not working but working with **www.mysite.com:8080/Application2/** ....How can I make it to work without port number?

Comment: You add again 2 lines for this second application, but it's a bit different as it is not the default application served under / . ProxyPass /Application2/ http://localhost:8080/Application2/
ProxyPassReverse /Application2/ http://localhost:8080/Application2/

Comment: not only for the second application but also for all tomcat application...when I tried by changing port number from 8080 to 80 in server.xml file, I am getting an error  like **Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at ilovesalesevents.com Port 80**

Comment: why change Tomcat's port ? It is Apache which is in front of Tomcat, and Apache sends all the traffic to Tomcat.

Comment: OK... If I have multiple applications how can I do this....Do I need to write **ProxyPass /Application2/ localhost:8080/Application2 ProxyPassReverse /Application2/ localhost:8080/Application2** for all the applications?

Comment: Yes. you need these 2 lines of config for each application. The default application that you want to be served under / , its config is given in my answer that you accepted.

Comment: Is there any other solution which works for all instead of doing it for everytime?

Comment: I wrote **ProxyPass /Application2/ http://localhost:8080/Application2 ProxyPassReverse /Application2/ http://localhost:8080/Application2**. When I call http://example.com/Application2, getting 404 error

Comment: Redirecting the default / to a webapplication makes this need to add configurations for other webapplications. If you have 404, something is wrong, probably you the trailing / is missing from what I see.